# How can I get the selected date from an Angular date picker and pass it to $http service parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am calling the AngularJS service $http and I would like to use the date value from an Angular-Material date picker component as a parameter in the below params **date value**.

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'theurltobeused',
    params : { pdate : **date value**}
...
```

Here is my angular-material date picker component

```
<div flex="20">
  <md-datepicker ng-model="data.myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="ctrl.minDate" md-max-date="ctrl.maxDate">
  </md-datepicker>
</div>
```

if i try

```
... params : {pdate : $scope.data.myDate}...
```

I get an error
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'myDate' of undefined**

Comment: I think you need to use `ng-model=ctrl.data.myDate`, since it appears you're using `ctrlAs` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juse use **`ctrl.data.mydate`**

```
 <md-datepicker ng-model="ctrl.data.mydate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="ctrl.minDate" md-max-date="ctrl.maxDate">
 </md-datepicker>
```

and then

```
 params : {pdate : this.data.mydate}.
```